# variables in url are being truncated

Tags: php, html, url, get, header

I am passing a website and a message through a url to another webpage. The website in its self contains some get variables. The problem comes from the fact that when the site and the message is passed, the site variables are being truncated. I have searched for a way to solve this and did not understand what others were doing. Thanks for the help in advance. The code is below:

```
<?php

   $I_D = 0;
   $EI_D = 1;  
   $site = "orowland/eval.php?eval=$I_D&stats=$EI_D";
   header("location:message.php?message=Site has been created&site=$site");

?>
```

In message.php:

```
<?php

   if (isset($_GET['message'])) 
   {
      $message = $_GET['message'];
      $site = $_GET['site'];
      echo $message;
      echo $site;
   }

?>
```

Output on page:

```
orowland/eval.php?eval=0
```

But the expected output is:

```
orowland/eval.php?eval=0&stats=1
```

Comment: I have tested and it's just fine for me.

Comment: I edited it, but i gives you the expected output?

Comment: Yes i'm having this output... http://imgur.com/It762wy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably a good idea to `urlencode()` that string as it contains spaces

So do

```
<?php
   $I_D = 0;
   $EI_D = 1;  
   $site = "orowland/eval.php?eval=$I_D&stats=$EI_D";
   $message = urlencode('Site has been created');
   $url = "message.php?message=$message&site=$site";
   header("location: $url");
?>
```

Comment: This one is easy for you right RiggsFolly? urlencode()  :)